# PHPUnit print tests execution time

Tags: php, phpunit, execution-time

is there a way to print the execution time of each test with PHPUnit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement your own test runner, for example by extending `PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner` and make it collect and print run times.

Comment: I was hoping there was a more "automatic" way to do that but i think that this is the best alternative

Comment: Data you ask for is being collected during test execution - you just need to save it to a file with an extra option - see my answer.

Answer (score 21):

To add some more ways:

---

You can write a [custom Test listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener) and [add it to the XML file](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners). In that listener you can access the `$testResult->time()`. Some lines in your phpunit.xml and a 10 line PHP class. Not too much hassle.

```
class SimpleTestListener implements PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener
{
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' ended and took %s seconds.\n", 
           $test->getName(),
           $test->time()
        );
    }
}
```

---

If you generate a junit.xml anyways (for CI or while creating code coverage) all the numbers are there anyways and with a simple XSLT you can make those even more readable.

Example junit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="DemoTest" file="/home/edo/foo.php" tests="2" assertions="2" failures="1" errors="0" time="0.007727">
    <testcase name="testPass" class="DemoTest" file="/home/edo/foo.php" line="4" assertions="1" time="0.003801"/>
    <testcase name="testFail" class="DemoTest" file="/home/edo/foo.php" line="8" assertions="1" time="0.003926">
      <failure type="PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException">DemoTest::testFail
Failed asserting that &lt;boolean:false&gt; is true.

/home/edo/foo.php:9
</failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

and with an transformation like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h1>Tests</h1>
    <xsl:for-each select="testsuites/testsuite">
      <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2>
      <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="testcase">
          <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> : <xsl:value-of select="@time"/>
            <xsl:if test="failure">
              <b>Failed !</b>
              <i><xsl:value-of select="*"/></i>
            </xsl:if>
          </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you get lines showing you: `<li>testPass : 0.003801</li>` (the HTML is just an example, it should be easily adaptable).

Referencing my own blog post here: https://edorian.github.io/2011-01-19-creating-your-custom-phpunit-output.formats/ for the xslt stuff.

Comment: My listener extends `PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener`, and I found `$test->time()` wouldn't work for elapsed time. However, based on a comment elsewhere on this page, `$test->getTestResultObject()->time()` works fine. `$time` is good for per-test time, too.

Comment: The first two links are dead. Could you update them and/or post some example code for adding it to the XML file?

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners

Answer (score 21):

Just add **--log-junit "my_tests_log.xml"** and then open this file with spreadsheet application (Excel, Numbers, Calc) to view it. You get all information you ask for, and you can sort by test execution time.

Comment: can't find a reader for this file. the first line show <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 9):

If you don't like to write a Testlistener, like it was suggested already, you can use the following script to parse the [PHPUnit's JSON Test Result](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/logging.html#logging.json) in an easier to read format:

```
alias phpunit-report-runtime="phpunit --log-json php://stdout \
    | awk '\$NF ~ '/,/' && \$1 ~ /\"(test|time)\"/' \
    | cut -d: -f2- \
    | sed \"N;s/\n/--/\"  \
    | sed \"s/,//\"   \
    | awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"--\"}; {print \$2 \$1}' | sort -r \
    | head -n 5"
```

Format is `<time in seconds>, <test method>`. Example output:

```
 $ phpunit-report-runtime
 0.29307007789612, "VCR\\Util\\SoapClientTest::testDoRequestHookDisabled"
 0.16475319862366, "VCR\\CassetteTest::testRecordAndPlaybackRequest"
 0.092710018157959, "VCR\\Util\\SoapClientTest::testDoRequest"
 0.031861782073975, "VCR\\LibraryHooks\\SoapTest::testShouldInterceptCallWhenEnabled"
 0.026772022247314, "VCR\\LibraryHooks\\AbstractFilterTest::testRegisterAlreadyRegistered"
```

Comment: Not possible in PHPUnit 6, as `--log-json` option was removed.

Answer (score 7):

Many of the current answers discuss how to access and analyze the duration times in the log file. I will share two ways to modify the CLI output in phpUnit version 3.7.38 (which is what Travis-CI uses for PHP by default), building on @edorian's [incomplete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285578/edorian).

---

Use a custom printer to override the CLI output. I can't find any documentation for printers but they appear to be supported. You can see which methods are available in the [source code](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/class-PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter.html).

```
class TestDurationPrinter extends PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter
{
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' ended and took %s seconds.\n", 
           $test->getName(),
           $time
        );
    }
}
```

Then add these lines as attributes to `phpunit` in the `phpunit.xml` file:

```
printerFile="path/to/TestDurationPrinter.php"
printerClass="TestDurationPrinter"
```

You can also use the `--printer` CLI option but that doesn't play well with namespaces.

---

You can add to the CLI output, as opposed to overriding it, with a TestListener by implementing the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener` interface (this is the same interface that printers use). This will still print `.`, `S`, and `F` so be sure to account for that, if you desire.

```
class TestDurationListener implements PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener
{
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' ended and took %s seconds.\n", 
           $test->getName(),
           $time
        );
    }

    public function addError(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {
    }

    public function addFailure(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e, $time)
    {
    }

    public function addIncompleteTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {
    }

    public function addRiskyTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {
    }

    public function addSkippedTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {
    }

    public function startTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test)
    {
    }

    public function startTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {
    }

    public function endTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {
    }
}
```

In version 3.8 and above there is a `PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener` that can be extended so that you only define the methods you want to override.

```
class TestDurationListener extends PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener
{
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' ended.\n", $test->getName());
    }
}
```

To include your new listener, add these lines to your `phpunit.xml` file:

```
<listeners>
    <listener class="TestDurationListener" file="path/to/TestDurationListener.php" />
</listeners>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a complete example based on the idea from edorians answer. Tested on PHPunit 4.

Create the following PHP class:

```
class ProfilingTestListener extends PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener
{
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' ended.\tTotal time %s s.\tTest time %s s.\n",
            str_pad($test->toString(), 50),
            number_format($test->getTestResultObject()->time(), 3),
            number_format($time, 3)
        );
    }
}
```

Add the following to your phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit ..>
    ...
    <listeners>
        <listener class="ProfilingTestListener"></listener>
    </listeners>
    ...
</phpunit>
```

---

Example output:

```
PHPUnit 4.7.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Test 'FooTest::testFoo              ' ended.    Total time 2.050 s. Test time 0.026 s. 
.Test 'FooTest::testBar             ' ended.    Total time 2.077 s. Test time 1.000 s.
.Test 'FooTest::testBar2            ' ended.    Total time 3.077 s. Test time 0.730 s.
```

Comment: I had to add a file property, `<listener class="ProfilingTestListener" file="ProfilingTestListener.php"></listener>`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could use the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods *(which are called at the beginning and end of each test, respectively)* to :

- Log the current time before the test, in `setUp`,
- And calculate the time the test took, in `tearDown`.

Of course, you'll have to do this in each one of your test classes -- or in a super-class which will be inherited by all your test classes.

Comment: It does this for you automatically.  There's no need to re-do it each time.  It's stored in the PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult instance for each test.  Simply call `$result->time();` to get the time spent...

Comment: Oh ; I learnt something, here, again :-) Thanks for the comment !

Comment: `Call to undefined method MyTest::time()` :(

Comment: `$this->getTestResultObject()->time()`?

Comment: How do you get the test method name from tearDown()?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can have it export the execution time with [Logging](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/logging.html).  It's not directly outputted as the result, but you could write a pretty report viewer that would output the results of the log file (either from JSON or XML).  That should get you what you want...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest solution is to export test statistic as json:

$ phpunit --log-json testExport.json

Comment: `--log-json` was deprecated and removed in PHPUnit 6.

Answer (score 0):

I liked @adri's answer. It got me started on this:

```
alias phpunittime=" | awk '\$NF ~ '/,/' && \$1 ~ /\"(test|time)\"/' \
    | cut -d: -f2- \
    | sed \"N;s/\n/--/\"  \
    | sed \"s/,//\"   \
    | awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"--\"}; {print \$2 \$1}' | sort -r \
    | head"
```

To use, you'll need to configure PHP unit to output to a JSON log file. To do so, make your `phpunit.xml` look like this:

```
<phpunit>
    <logging>
        <log type="json" target="/tmp/logfile.json"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Then use like this:

```
$ cat /tmp/logfile.json | phpunittime
```

To see more or less than 10 timings, say 2 or 19, use `-n 2` or `-n 19`, respectively, at the end.

What's nice about this is it doesn't make assumptions about how you call/run phpunit itself (in my case, I use CakePHP and run my command like this: `Console/cake test app`). Also, you can run your tests and see their output as normal... your terminal doesn't just sit there until the tests are done.