# Phpunit test with disabled error handling is totally slow

Tags: php, error-handling, phpunit

I've refactored some code and introduced deprecation warnings with [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/trigger_error) and the `E_USER_DEPRECATED` constant.

Therefore I needed to modify the test that is touching that feature

```
public function testMethod()
{
    $expected = 'value';
    $actual   = $this->subject->callDeprecatedMethod();
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual)
}
```

So that the method call does not raise the exception (e.g. as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8412746/367456) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1225776/367456)):

```
public function testMethod()
{
    $expected = 'value';

    $save = PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Deprecated::$enabled;
    PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Deprecated::$enabled = false;
    $actual = $this->subject->callDeprecatedMethod();
    PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Deprecated::$enabled = save;

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual)
}
```

This worked fine, however I realized that when running all tests, the testrunner took much much longer at one dot suddenly and by [checking against JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5196868/367456) and also in PHPStorm that for this just changed `testMethod` the timings went up from milliseconds to 0.71 seconds.

How can I prevent this?

I need my tests to run fast fast fast :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that in case of an error, the PHPUnit error handler does keep some of the information desipite the error exceptions are disabled. As those backtraces can be larger, I assume this is iterating those plus handling the data.

So my idea was to get the error handler out of the equation - thanks to storing `$actual` results to variables - and re-enable PHPUnits error handler then again:

```
public function testMethod()
{
    $expected = 'value';

    $noop = function() {};
    $previous = set_error_handler($noop);

    $actual = $this->subject->callDeprecatedMethod();

    set_error_handler($previous);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual)
}
```

This brings back the original timings.

Actually, a similar effect has to use the error suppression operator as I then found out. Albeit it doesn't disable the handler from PHPUnit, the fast timings are restored:

```
public function testMethod()
{
    $expected = 'value';

    $actual = @$this->subject->callDeprecatedMethod();

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual)
}
```

It is also more comfortable to use.